# Join by substring ranges?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a MS Access 2003 database table containing a list of tenanted properties owned by large landlords. It has a field 'PARISH', which is always a 4 digit string. The first two characters are a unique code to denote the landlord (owner) of a given property. E.g. 'SP' for 'Silverline Properties', or BL for 'Badhest Lettings'.  The the second two characters represent a location code of the property - e.g. HU for Humbervale, EK for Eastkirk, etc.

Each property is allocated to a certain processing team using this 4 digit code. There are ten teams.

One landlord can have properties in muliple locations. Some teams deal with all landlord's properties, regardless of location. Other teams deal with a portion of the landlord's properties based on location.

There is a lookup table (dbo_Mail_Routing) to identify which team deals with a property. It does this via a low range and high range field, for example :-

```
LOW_RANGE, HIGH_RANGE, TEAM
SPAA, SPZZ, Team1
BLAA, BLZZ, Team2 

ADAA, ADAZ, Team7
ADBA, ADBD, Team8
ADBE, ADMR, Team9
ADMS, ADMT, Team10

LCAA, LCAD, Team10
LCAF, LCAz, Team2
LCBA, LCFz, Team7 
LCGA, LCzz  Team5
```

The 'PARISH' field is compared with the code ranges in the lookup table above to see which team deals with the property. The PARISH field must fit within the 'range' of codes between the low and high values. There are a mixture of scenarios here :-

1. One row in lookup table for a given LL, with AA through ZZ for location - simple enough. All properties regardless of the third and fourth characters in PARISH, match to that one team
2. Multiple rows for one LL, but where low_range and high_range is the same value - again simple enough, just map the PARISH field to the LOW_RANGE field WHERE they are equal
3. Multiple rows for one LL, but with different ranges of location code.

How can I properly get from the 4 digit PARISH field to the relevant Team?

So far I can deal with scenarios 1 and 2 above as

```
SELECT a.*, b.TEAM
FROM tblPROPS a
INNER JOIN dbo_Mail_Routing b ON b.LOW_RANGE = a.PARISH
WHERE b.LOW_RANGE = b.HIGH_RANGE

UNION ALL

SELECT a.*, b.TEAM
FROM tblPROPS a
INNER JOIN dbo_Mail_Routing b ON LEFT(a.PARISH, 2) = LEFT(b.LOW_RANGE, 2)
WHERE b.LOW_RANGE <> b.HIGH_RANGE
AND RIGHT(b.LOW_RANGE, 2) = "AA"
AND RIGHT(b.HIGH_RANGE, 2) = "ZZ"
```

Is there a way to query in access that a two digit character string is within a 'range' ?

Comment: It's very easy to show them as two separate fields in my table, but I cannot change the lookup table. So you still have the problem of the location ranges.

Comment: I'm not sure about Access, but in plain SQL this would be `ON  a.PARISH BETWEEN b.LOW_RANGE AND b.HIGH_RANGE`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that BETWEEN could be used for letters - I thought it was only numbers and dates!

Comment: `BETWEEN` on strings might not always return the expected result as it depends on the session's sort order and might also depend on case sensitivity. If you're only using `A` to `Z` in uppercase this should be fine, but double check if you get what you need...